# The "an account" link (displayed with with "add comment") returns a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface, hyperlinks

I was checking out Stack Apps and wanted to log in. I clicked "an account"…

[image: add comment (requires an account with 1 reputation)]

…and the site returns a 404 Page Not Found:

[image: 404 Page Not Found]

Apparently the "add account" link is linking to `http://site-name/help/users/login`, which is an invalid destination. It should actually be `http://site-name/users/login`.

This is happening across the network, reproduced on Stack Apps, Stack Overflow, and Meta.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that "add account" link is linking to `http://site-name/help/users/login`
which actually should be `http://site-name/users/login`

E.g.
Current link on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/users/login

Which actually should be: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login